# Dell Latitude E5430, Windows 10 normal boot black screen but in safe mode the is ok

Tags: windows-10, driver, intel, vga

I have a little problem with a Dell Latitude E5430 laptop with original Windows 10 Pro. After clean install the laptop is full functional. But... if the Windows Update install the lastest Intel HD 4000 driver, the laptop internal screen will be black. The internal screen works only in Safe Mode and the hdmi/vga ports are full functional. Its looks like the Win10 Pro doesnt recognize the internal screen.

In the Safe Mode the monitor drivers are disabled, and the internal screen work correctly, in the correct resolution.

Have anybody any idea? :)

I tried to:
 - install Intel HD 4000 drivers /old one/lastest, doesnt work
 - find different display driver, but i cant find anything.

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: [disable auto update](https://superuser.com/a/1068961/174557) of the Intel HD drivers and rollback to the default driver which works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but the Windows 10 doesnt allow. First of all I removed the driver. After I tried to install the old one but I cant because the installer given error message. The message was something lile this: cpu doesnt match or the operating system doesnt right. But the driver is the same intel hd 4000 Windows 10 64bit just older.

Comment: install the driver via device manager , not via setup.exe

Comment: Thanks the tip. Ill try as soon as possible.

Comment: Okay, status update. I reinstalled the Win10 Pro, and I checked what happened. First of all, in the Win10 installer and after the install the internal display has the correct 1600x900 resolution, but doesnt have GPU driver. After the install in the device manager showed: Generic PNP monitor and Generic VGA driver.

Comment: Then I tried to install a old one intel hd 4000 driver. The internal screen still black after boot, but the analog VGA external output is full correctly. But, if i tried the lastest driver, the internal screen is still black, but the external screen is in the internal resolution, and I cant change it (internal: 1600x900, external: FHD).

Comment: E5430 lastest bios: A18 - nonvPro. With this bios the laptop lcd work correctly. I tried to install a older bios: A16, but with this the lcd backlight arent turn on, and after the boot ofc the lcd still black. So I reinstalled the A18 lastest bios.  What now?:D

Comment: looks like you're SOL. The HD4000 is not supported by Intel anymore. if it works, fine, if not you can't get support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay its ready!

It was the display cable. I removed the internal display cable and used wd40. Then I installed back and the screen is back to business.

Answer (score -2):

I just troubleshot a similar problem successfully.  I want to post this so it will come up in people's searches and maybe help them in the future.

My situation my dell would boot through is logo but the video card would stop outputting anything after that.  Black screen,  but also characterized by the monitor going into power save,  and the led on the monitor slowly blinking.

Once in the menu that let's you navigate to safe mode I booted into that mode and found it was able to do so.  All scans of hardware came up saying it was fine. No errors.

Internet says 3rd party drivers can stop windows boot,  if they're corrupted or the like.  My machine has a 3rd party graphics card that gives me some problems occasionally.  Seems related to what I'm observing,  so I roll that drive back to a windows basic display adapter driver.  (Via device manager) -- Reboot but problem doesn't go away.

I recall I recently installed drivers for a Wacom one tablet.  So I went ahead and removed that device via device manager.  After rebooting this time the problem resolved.